ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects when installing gym in anaconda env
I was following a chapter in the book SUDHARSAN RAVICHANDIRAN - HANDS-ON REINFORCEMENT LEARNING WITH PYTHON - _ master reinforcement and deep reinforcement. There's a handson exercise to work with Gym toolkit in a separate anaconda environment. In there I had to follow couple of steps to install necessary tools in my Xubuntu machine.

Open the Terminal and type the following command to download Anaconda: wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
After downloading, we can install Anaconda using the following command: bash Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
Create a virtual environment using the following command and name our environment universe: conda create --name universe python=3.6 anaconda
Activate it: source activate universe
Install the following dependencies:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang libcupti-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev make tmux
htop chromium-browser git cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev xvfb libav-tools
xorg-dev python-opengl libboost-all-dev libsdl2-dev swig
conda install pip six libgcc swig
conda install opencv 


Install Gym: pip install gym==0.15.4

Then it took a considerable time and gave following logs
Collecting gym==0.15.4
  Using cached gym-0.15.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.10.0.82.tar.gz (95.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0
  Using cached pyglet-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.5.0)
Collecting cloudpickle~=1.2.0
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym==0.15.4) (0.18.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... -
set of Installing commands
...
  Copying files from CMake output
  creating directory _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/python-3/cv2.abi3.so -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/cv2.abi3.so
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/__init__.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/__init__.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/load_config_py2.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/load_config_py2.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/load_config_py3.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/load_config_py3.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/config.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/config.py
  copying _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/python/cv2/config-3.py -> _skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install/cv2/config-3.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/damiboy123/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/damiboy123/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/damiboy123/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 262, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kazhr26h/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 231, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kazhr26h/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kazhr26h/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kazhr26h/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 543, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 316, in main
      cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kazhr26h/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 683, in setup
      cmake_install_dir,
    File "setup.py", line 456, in _classify_installed_files_override
      raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
  Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2/py.typed'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

please consider I had to do some modifications to above mentioned commands, since the last edition is 4 years later and some of commands weren't working. ie:

libav-tools has been replaced by ffmpeg and python-opengl by PyOpenGL

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install PyOpenGL
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

and I followed stackoverflow thread, but there wasn't any remedy.

Try pip install --only-binary ":all:" opencv-python first, then try installing gym again

as FlyingTeller has commented, I ran pip install --only-binary ":all:" opencv-python and installed gym in the anaconda env. Then I got following log:
Collecting gym==0.15.4
  Using cached gym-0.15.4-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.5.0)
Collecting pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0
  Using cached pyglet-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting cloudpickle~=1.2.0
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (4.6.0.66)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from gym==0.15.4) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: future in ./anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym==0.15.4) (0.18.2)
Installing collected packages: pyglet, cloudpickle, gym
  Attempting uninstall: cloudpickle
    Found existing installation: cloudpickle 1.5.0
    Uninstalling cloudpickle-1.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled cloudpickle-1.5.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
distributed 2.20.0 requires cloudpickle>=1.3.0, but you have cloudpickle 1.2.2 which is incompatible.

according to incompatibilities I ran: pip install pyqt5==5.12.3 pyqtwebengine==5.12.1
after that I ran pip install gym==0.15.4 and there were no errors!
